# IE6 buggy position:fixed rendering with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have a page with a fixed background image that is supposed to stretch to fill the entire viewport. To achieve this I have body height set to 100% and overflow to auto. Unfortunately this triggers that hoary old IE6 positioning bug where anything set to position:absolute behaves as though it is fixed.

This is part of a CMS template so it's not really feasible to fix the height of the viewport when different pages are of wildly different heights.

What other options do I have? Either different ways of stretching the background images or ways of preventing the IE6 positioning bug from triggering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Johnathan Snook has a [article on the IE6 bug](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie/) and its fix. I hope this solves the problem.